# Is it possible to use transform: scaleX() without affecting the border-radius?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to generate a simple expanding bar animation. Everything works find and I control it to my liking, except for the changing `border-radius` which is affected by the `scaleX()` transformation. Is there a way to avoid this effect?

I assumed using an absolute unit for `border-radius` would suffice but it doesn't. `scaleX()` still affects it.

*Important note:*

I want to use `scaleX()` rather than working with the `width` property because the elements i am working on come with various changing widths and I want to have only one animation to work with them all.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation: expand;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes expand {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0.1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div />
```

Comment: There's some [good articles](https://css-tricks.com/various-methods-for-expanding-a-box-while-preserving-the-border-radius/) about this out on the interwebs (the most helpful portion is towards the bottom). Cheers

Comment: Problem is border radius is affected by the overall width of the element, have you considered scaling border radius as well? as part of your animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use scaleX() rather than working with the width property because the elements i am working on come with various changing widths and I want to have only one animation to work with them all.

Don't specify the `to` and your animation will work with any width:

```css
.bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation: expand;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes expand {
  from {
    width:20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>

<div class="bar" style="width:100px"></div>
<div class="bar" style="width:40px"></div>
```

Comment: That's great. It also solved the border-radius issue. Thanks!

Comment: It does not use scaleX().

Comment: I did and it says "I want to use scaleX() rather than working with the width property"

Comment: @crg read until the end ...